# How to update mysql mapping table which contains id mapping of two different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one is blog_posts another categories

```
id     | post_name
------ | ------
1      | title1  
2      | title2

id     | category_name
------ | ------
1      | category1  
2      | category2
```

and for the mapping of the post and category I'm using another table like

```
id     | post_id | category_id
------ | ------- | -----------
1      |    1    |     2
2      |    2    |     1
3      |    2    |     2
```

so now when I update a post and select some different category id(s) for the post then how should I update the mapping table?

what I use is I delete all the mapping records for the currently being edited post then re-insert the selected category id(s) along with post id to the mapping table, is this approach a best practice? please share your ideas.
Thank you

Comment: Add one new row to the mapping table for each new category selected using the post_id, new category_id

Comment: That approach is often used to simplify the process so you dont have to identify new and deleted categories

Comment: Instead of UPDATE or INSERT use REPLACE query to create record in table. REPLACE will create record if it do not exists

Comment: When you select different category then first of all get all stored categories for that post. After that create array for database post category & form post category. After to take diff delete category form post which is not selected but stored in database. for insert diff of selected post category & database post category. For example you can check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
$post_id = "2";

$db_categories = array('1', '2');

$select_categories = array('1', '3');

$delete_post_categories = array_diff($db_categories, $select_categories); //to delete result array('2')

$insert_posr_categories = array_diff($select_categories, $db_categories); //to insert result array('3')

print_r($delete_post_categories);
print_r($insert_posr_categories);
```

Comment: @devsourav if my answer is useful for you than please upvote. Thank you.

Comment: I tried but my reputation is below 15 :)  so stackoverflow not allowing me to do so.